# Error when embed code ckeditor and kcfinder in php

Tags: ckeditor, image-uploading, kcfinder

Error when embed code ckeditor and kcfinder in php.

The main problem I am can't upload img in localhost.

"Image source URL is missing" when upload.

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show some codes

Comment: Config.js in ckeditor:
 
Config.php in kcfinder:
 
Embed ckeditor in texterea :